# Conditional display with Dojo MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo

I have a dojox/mvc/Repeat area which is bound to an array of records.

Within the row of the Repeat there is a field (the id of the record) which should be a simple display Output if the record has already been saved to the database, but it should be a TextBox if the record is new (the user must enter the value).

How do I solve this elegantly? I am fairly new to Dojo and its MVC part is very under-documented.

Comment: you can use the transforms to set the disabled variable to either true of false.  If you use parse transfor, that is called on the way out, format, is on the way in.  will try to put a fiddle together.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have different items displayed for the two states of the record, so simply binding the disabled attribute of a TextBox with a transformer is not really an option. I am working on a fiddle which could bind the display property of the 2 items with different transformers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A secondary, less complex solution:

Bind the "hasBeenSaved" property to a hidden text within the repeating div.

Put an onChange event on the hidden field which gets the index of the repeat as well.

The onChange event simply hides the field which is not appropriate in light of the hasBeenChanged property value for the record.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/asoltesz/8u9js6sz/5/

Code:

```
hasBeenSavedChanged = function(field, index) {
    var divToHide
    if (field.value == true) {
        divToHide = "idInputDiv"
    }
    else {
        divToHide = "idOutputDiv"
    }
    var div = document.getElementById(divToHide + index);
    div.style.display = "none";
}

require([
    "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    'dojox/mvc/getStateful'
 ], function(
     declare, domStyle, parser, ready, 
     _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin,
     getStateful
 ){

    // setting up the data model for MVC
     model = {
         items: [
            {   id: 'id1',
                hasBeenSaved: true
            },
            {   id: null,
                hasBeenSaved: false
            },
            {   id: null,
                hasBeenSaved: false
            },
            {   id: 'id3',
                hasBeenSaved: true
            }
        ]
    };
    model = getStateful(model); 

     ready(function(){
         // Call the parser manually so it runs after our mixin is defined, and page has finished loading
         parser.parse();
     });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>

<div 
  data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" 
  data-dojo-props="target: model"
>
    <span id="itemsCtl"
        data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/ListController"
        data-dojo-props="model: model.items">
    </span>

    <div id="itemsRepeat" 
      data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Repeat" 
      data-dojo-props="children: at('rel:', 'items')"
    >
        <div 
            data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group"
            data-dojo-props="target: at('rel:', ${this.index})"
        >
            <span>Record: ${this.index}</span>

            <input 
                id="hasBeenChanged${this.index}"
                data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" 
                data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'hasBeenSaved')"
                onChange="hasBeenSavedChanged(this, '${this.index}');"
                type="hidden"
            ></input>

            <!-- This is displayed only when the record is new (not saved yet) -->            
            <div id="idInputDiv${this.index}"
            >
                <label for="idInput${this.index}">id:</label>
                <input 
                    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" 
                    id="idInput${this.index}"
                    data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'id')"
                ></input>
            </div> <!-- end conditionally hidden div -->

            <!-- This is displayed only when the record has already been saved -->
            <div id="idOutputDiv${this.index}" >
                <label for="idInput${this.index}">id:</label>
                <span
                    data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Output" 
                    id="idOutput${this.index}"
                    data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'id')"
                ></span>
            </div> <!-- end conditionally hidden div -->

            <hr/>

        </div> <!-- end of row -->
    </div> <!-- end of Repeat -->
</div> <!-- end of Group -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The most MVC-ish solution I have found so far is as follows:

1)
I put a "hasBeenSaved" property into the model which will mark the server-side saved state of the record. This attribute will be bound to the view with a transformation since the "display" style attribute of the DIV will be bound to the hasBeenSaved model attribute (one is a boolean the other is a string: "block"/"none").

2)
Within the Row, I put a conditionally visible div around the id input field. This will be visible only when the record is new, so its display style attribute is bound with an appropriate transformer attached to the Dojo MVC binding. 
The same is done for the id output field but the transformer is different on the binding since this will be displayed only when the record has already been saved.

The JSFiddle which I have used to prototype this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/asoltesz/6t4dj1w7/15/

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    'dojox/mvc/getStateful'
 ], function(
     declare, domStyle, parser, ready, 
     _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin,
     getStateful
 ){

    // setting up the data model for MVC
     model = {
         items: [
            {   id: 'id1',
                hasBeenSaved: true
            },
            {   id: null,
                hasBeenSaved: false
            },
            {   id: null,
                hasBeenSaved: false
            },
            {   id: 'id3',
                hasBeenSaved: true
            }
        ]
    };
    model = getStateful(model); 

     /**
      * This mixin makes it possible to set the "display" style property of 
      * the DOM node (of any widget) as a Widget property and thus bind it to an MVC model
      * when needed.
      */
     declare("_DisplayAttributeMixin", [], {
         // parameters
         display: "block",

         _setDisplayAttr: function(/*String*/ display){
             this._set("display", display);
             domStyle.set(this.domNode, "display", display);
         }
     });
     /** Transformer methods for converting hasBeenSaved to visible/hidden values */
     transfSavedToHidden = {format: function(hasBeenSaved){
         console.log("transfSavedToHidden: " + (hasBeenSaved ? "none" : "block"));
         return hasBeenSaved ? "none" : "block";
     }};     
     transfSavedToVisible = {format: function(hasBeenSaved){
         console.log("transfSavedToHidden: " + (hasBeenSaved ? "block" : "none"));
         return hasBeenSaved ? "block" : "none";
     }};     

     ready(function(){
         // Call the parser manually so it runs after our mixin is defined, and page has finished loading
         parser.parse();
     });
 });
```

The HTML markup:

```
<script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>

<div 
  data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" 
  data-dojo-props="target: model"
>
    <div id="repeatId" 
      data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Repeat" 
      data-dojo-props="children: at('rel:', 'items')"
    >
        <div 
            data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group"
            data-dojo-props="target: at('rel:', ${this.index})"
        >
            <span>Record: ${this.index}</span>

            <!-- This is displayed only when the record is new (not saved yet) -->            
            <div 
                data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" 
                data-dojo-mixins="_DisplayAttributeMixin" 
                data-mvc-bindings="
                    display: at('rel:', 'hasBeenSaved')
                      .direction(at.from)
                      .transform(transfSavedToHidden)"
            >
                <label for="idInput${this.index}">id:</label>
                <input 
                    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" 
                    id="idInput${this.index}"
                    data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'id')"
                ></input>
            </div> <!-- end conditionally hidden div -->

            <!-- This is displayed only when the record has already been saved -->
            <div 
                data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase" 
                data-dojo-mixins="_DisplayAttributeMixin" 
                data-mvc-bindings="
                    display: at('rel:', 'hasBeenSaved')
                      .direction(at.from)
                      .transform(transfSavedToVisible)"
            >
                <label for="idInput${this.index}">id:</label>
                <span
                    data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Output" 
                    id="idOutput${this.index}"
                    data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'id')"
                ></span>
            </div> <!-- end conditionally hidden div -->

            <hr/>

        </div> <!-- end of row -->
    </div> <!-- end of Repeat -->
</div> <!-- end of Group -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixin/transformer approach is something I had in mind, too. Two things I’d add there are out-of-the-box Dijit features, one is `dijitDisplayNone` class, another is [attribute mapping](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#mapping-widget-attributes-to-domnode-attributes) feature.

Though it’s strange that the former is undocumented, the intent may have been for private usage within Dijit codebase.

Though it’s a bit hackish (and may be broken in future 1.x Dijit releases), overriding the Dijit code that’s responsible for [attribute mapping](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#mapping-widget-attributes-to-domnode-attributes) will allow you to map a widget attribute to a CSS class that’s toggled.

Here’s a code sample that uses the above two:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dijit/themes/dijit.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: 1, parseOnLoad: 0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/_base/declare",
                "dojo/_base/lang",
                "dojo/dom-class",
                "dojo/parser",
                "dojox/mvc/getStateful",
                "dijit/form/TextBox"
            ], function(array, declare, lang, domClass, parser, getStateful){
                declare("CssToggleMixin", null, {
                    // summary:
                    //      Mixin class to support widget attributes with toggleClass type.
                    //      toggleClass type allows boolean value of an attribute to reflect existence of a CSS class in a DOM node in the widget.

                    _attrToDom: function(/*String*/ attr, /*String*/ value, /*Object?*/ commands){
                        // summary:
                        //      Handle widget attribute with toggleClass type.
                        //      See dijit/_WidgetBase._attrToDom() for more details.

                        var callee = arguments.callee;
                        array.forEach((function(){ return lang.isArray(commands) ? commands.slice(0) : [commands]; })(arguments.length >= 3 ? commands : this.attributeMap[attr]), function(command){
                            command.type != "toggleClass" ?
                             this.inherited("_attrToDom", lang.mixin([attr, value, command], {callee: callee})) :
                             domClass.toggle(this[command.node || "domNode"], command.className || attr, value);
                        }, this);
                    }
                });
                flipConverter = {
                    format: function (value) {
                        return !value;
                    },
                    parse: function (value) {
                        return !value;
                    }
                };
                model = getStateful({
                     items: [
                        {
                            value: "Foo",
                            hasBeenSaved: true
                        },
                        {
                            hasBeenSaved: false
                        },
                        {
                            hasBeenSaved: false
                        },
                        {
                            value: "Bar",
                            hasBeenSaved: true
                        }
                    ]
                });
                parser.parse();
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/WidgetList"
            data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
            data-dojo-props="children: at(model, 'items')">
            <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
                <div>
                    <span data-dojo-type="dijit/_WidgetBase"
                        data-dojo-mixins="CssToggleMixin"
                        data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'value'),
                                         noDisplay: at('rel:', 'hasBeenSaved').transform(flipConverter),
                                         _setValueAttr: {node: 'domNode', type: 'innerText'},
                                         _setNoDisplayAttr: {type: 'toggleClass', className: 'dijitDisplayNone'}"></span>
                    <span data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                        data-dojo-mixins="CssToggleMixin"
                        data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'value'),
                                         noDisplay: at('rel:', 'hasBeenSaved'),
                                         _setNoDisplayAttr: {type: 'toggleClass', className: 'dijitDisplayNone'}"></span>
                </div>
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it’ll shed some light.

Best, Akira

Comment: Very insightful answer. I think I will save the CssToggleMixin for later reuse, it looks like a powerful way to use properties for class switching. Sounds like something that should be a core part of Dijit.